# Regexp in php matching two (or more) words in string

Tags: php, regex

What I'm trying to do is to check if certain keywords are present in a string. Matching single words is not a problem, however I can't figure out how to get it to work if for example two words need to match.

This is what I got so far

```
$filter = array('single','bar');

$text = 'This is the string that needs to be checked, with single and mutliple words';

$matches = array();

$regexp = "/\b(" . implode($filter,"|") . ")\b/i";

$matchFound = preg_match_all(
                $regexp, 
                $text, 
                $matches
              );


if ($matchFound) {
    foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
        echo $match . "\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to create a regular expression that returns true if both `string` and `checked` are matched. If I need to use two expressions thats not a problem.

As an logical statement it would be something like this: `single || bar || (string && checked)`

Comment: Do you only want to know if the string contains these words or are you planning on working with `$matches` afterwards?

Comment: No that is not needed. At this time I only need to check if the words are present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for the occurance of all words, using a variable as flag should suffice (and checking each word independently), instead of one big regular expression.

```
$filter = array('single','bar');
$foundAll = true;
foreach ($filter as $searchFor) {
    $pattern = "/\b(" . $searchFor . ")\b/i";
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $string)) {
        $foundAll = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is (if I am not mistaken) that it also will match banana in bananashake and that is not what I want, I only want the whole words to be matched.

Comment: @MThomas: in this case, you can use `preg_match()` instead of `stripos()` with this code (and add word boundaries in the pattern) (and exit the loop at the first false).

Comment: I got this to work, thanks for the help. I accepted this one since it gives me the option to work with the matches, that is not needed now but might be usefull in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to do this with regex, you could use:

```
$regex = "";
foreach ($filter as $word) {
    $regex .= "(?=.*\b".$word."\b)";
}
$regex = "/".$regex."^.*$/i";
```

For the words `single` and `bar` the regex produced is: `/(?=.*\bsingle\b)(?=.*\bbar\b)^.*$`

You don't need to loop through the matches because this will only match once and the match will be the whole string (assuming all the words are present).

```
$matchFound = preg_match($regex, $text);
print($matchFound); // 0 for "single","bar". 1 for "single","checked"
```

Comment: Yup, each `(?=.*\bWORD\b)` starts looking from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining your actual code, could be a way to explore, checking if arrays have the same values with `array_diff`:

```
$filter = array('single','bar');

$text = 'This is the string that needs to be checked, with single and mutliple words';

$regexp = "/\b(" . implode($filter,"|") . ")\b/i";

$matchFound = preg_match_all($regexp, $text, $matches);

$matchFound = !!array_diff($filter, $matches[1]); //<- false if no diffs

if ($matchFound) {
    ...
```

`!!array_diff` returns false if no diffs, meaning all keys of `$filter` are found in `$text`